# JavaScript all On/Off button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 6 buttons and I wish to create a master button which will turn all the other buttons on or off. I managed to do that but ran into a problem when the master button would turn a button off if it was already on. I need this button to turn all the buttons on or off regardless of its previous state.Button 7 will be acting as master button. Thank you for taking the time to read this, any help would be much appreciated.

```
//master button

function button7(){
    currentvalue = document.getElementById('button7').value;
      if(currentvalue == "Off"){
        document.getElementById("button7").value="On";
      }else{
        document.getElementById("button7").value="Off";
      }
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#button7').on('click', function(){
                    $('#button7').toggleClass('on');
                    $('#button1').toggleClass('on');
                    $('#button2').toggleClass('on');
                    $('#button3').toggleClass('on');
                    $('#button4').toggleClass('on');
                    $('#button5').toggleClass('on');
                    $('#button6').toggleClass('on');
                    if(currentvalue == "Off"){
                    alert("off")
                }
                    else{
                    alert("on")
                }
        });
    });


//regular button  

function button1(){
        currentvalue = document.getElementById('button1').value;
          if(currentvalue == "Off"){
            document.getElementById("button1").value="On";
          }else{
            document.getElementById("button1").value="Off";
          }
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#button1').on('click', function(){
                        $(this).toggleClass('on');
                        if(currentvalue == "Off"){
                        alert("off")
                    }
                        else{
                        alert("on")
                    }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi, it's not clear what the problem seems to be. What's the problem that you mention when the buttons were already on? They wont turn off?

Comment: So what you mean is a master button that "toggles" all the button?...

Comment: sorry for being unclear, the problem is say a normal button is already turned on, then you hit the master button it will turn that normal button off, but I want for it to stay on.

Comment: You should use the jQuery tag if you're using jQuery variables/functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set all the buttons to a specific state, don't use `toggleClass()` which, as the name itself suggests, is used to *toggle* class-names. Instead:

```
$('#button7').on('click', function(){
    // select all the elements by their id:
    $('#button1,#button2,#button3')
    // remove both classes:
    .removeClass('on off')
    // add the class that the clicked-button currently represents:
    .addClass(this.value)
    // whatever Boolean the button currently represents,
    // switch to the other option:
    .val(this.value === 'On' ? 'Off' : 'On');
});
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 1):

Toggle the class on the button, the check if it has that class and use that to add or remove the class on all the other buttons. Using a boolean value as the second parameter to `toggleClass` will add or remove the class according to the boolean, not the presence of the class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button7').on('click', function(){
    $('#button7').toggleClass('on');
    var currentvalue = $('#button7').hasClass('on');
    $('#button1').toggleClass('on', curentvalue);
    $('#button2').toggleClass('on', curentvalue);
    $('#button3').toggleClass('on', curentvalue);
    $('#button4').toggleClass('on', curentvalue);
    $('#button5').toggleClass('on', curentvalue);
    $('#button6').toggleClass('on', curentvalue);
    if (currentvalue){
      alert("on")
    } else {
      alert("off")
    }
  });
});
```